# I'm having a lot of trouble trying to modify a "this" object from within a pseudo javascript class when it's already been initialized

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, express, commonjs

**Scroll down to the bottom of this post to see a work around / possible solution.**

This is probably easier just to explain in the source code with comments. The issue at hand is I cannot figure out how pseudo classes work together to perform the task I'm trying to do (explained in the code below).

The code is broken down into 3 files: lead.js, router.js, and db.js.

There are a decent amount of lines of code but most of it is comments.

```js
[lead.js]

var bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
    validators = require('../lib/validators'),
    utility = require('../lib/utility'),
    document = {};

var Lead = module.exports = function (db) {
  // Save a reference to the database.
  this.db = db;

  // Reference initial document.
  // This is totally wrong, not sure how to 'send' a variable to the constructor of a class
  // when I cannot add another param. Due to how I'm importing the db model, I won't know what
  // the document is until I fill out the form. I've also tried 'document' instead of 'Lead.document'.
  this.document = Lead.document;

  // Setup the document if it exists.
  // This also doesn't work.
  // Basically I want to be able to set up a document variable outside of this module (line #100),
  // Then pass it to this module after filling it up with values from a form.
  // Then based on what's been filled in, it would fix up (trim, convert to lower case)
  // some of the values automatically and default a few values that I'm not always going to pass.
  if (!document) {
    var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10),
        hash = bcrypt.hashSync(utility.generatePassword(), salt);

    // Default values.
    if (!document.meta.createdAt) { this.document.meta.createdAt = Date.now(); }
    if (!document.login.password) { this.document.login.password = hash; }
    if (!document.login.role) { this.document.login.role = 'User'; }

    // Normalize a few values.
    this.document.login.email = document.login.email.toLowerCase().trim();
    this.document.contact.name.first = document.contact.name.first.trim();
    this.document.contact.name.last = document.contact.name.last.trim();
    this.document.contact.address.street = document.contact.address.street.trim();
    this.document.contact.address.city = document.contact.address.city.trim();
    this.document.contact.address.state = document.contact.address.state.trim();
    this.document.contact.address.zip = document.contact.address.zip.trim();
    this.document.contact.phone.home = document.contact.phone.home.trim();
  }
  // So in regards to the above code, the end result I'm looking for is...
  // I want to append some properties to the this.document reference when the document is empty (when I'm updating it, I won't set the document), 
  // and on new documents it will append a few default values/normalize all the fields.
};

Lead.prototype.validate = function(fn) {
  var errors = [];

  // Some validation rules I cut out to make this shorter.

  if (errors.length) return fn(errors);
  fn();
};

Lead.prototype.save = function(fn) {
  this.db.collection('leads', function(err, collection) {
    if (err) { fn(new Error({message: err})); }

    collection.insert(this.document, function(err, result) {
      return fn(err, result);
    });
  });
};

---

[route.js file]

  var db = require('../models/db');

  app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body.lead || {};

    // Fill the document.
    var document = {
      meta: {
        host: req.headers.host,
        referer: req.headers.referer,
        createdIPAddress: req.connection.remoteAddress
      },
      login: {
        email: data.email
      },
      contact: {
        name: {
          first: data.first,
          last: data.last
        },
        address: {
          street: data.street,
          city: data.city,
          state: data.state,
          zip: data.zip
        },
        phone: {
          home: data.phone
        }
      }
    };

    // Write the document.
    db.lead.document = document;

    db.lead.validate(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        req.session.error = err;
        return res.redirect('back');
      }

      db.lead.save(function(err) {
        res.redirect('/register/success');
      });
    });
  });

---
[db.js]

var mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    server = new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017),
    connection = new mongodb.Db('test', server);

connection.open(function(err, db) {});

module.exports =  {
  lead: new (require('./lead'))(connection)
};
```

When I run this, my validator always reports that the password is empty which makes sense. I'm sending the document initially to the class with an empty password (the password is randomly generated, not a form field) -- the problem is I have no idea what to do with the if (!document) ... code block to actually set the this.document properly.

I hope between the comments and code you can get an idea of what I'm trying to do. I've been stuck on this for a while.

**EDIT**

I changed the flow of it a bit to get a solution.

In the db.js, I exported the connection rather than instantiating the lead (and future models) directly.

In the router.js file, I require the db and lead file, then pass both the db connection and the document in the constructor of the Lead. Ex.

```
var lead = new Lead(db, document);
```

In the lead.js file, it becomes as simple as doing this.document = document (same as the db). When I submit a new lead, the values I don't send over from router.js get appended to the document (the created date, a random password, etc.) and everything is good.

Is this a decent way of handling this, or is there a better way to refactor this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [read up on object-oriented programming in Javascript](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm).

The anonymous function you're defining near the top of your code *is* the constructor function, so with respect to the `document` property you want that is currently uninitialized, just type something like:

```
this.document = null;
```

Then some time later when you create a new object using this constructor, like so:

```
var myLead = new Lead(dbConnection);
```

You'll have the `myLead.document` property.

There are many other things wrong with your code, though. Why are you assuming that there is a global `document` variable with relevant data visible in your library when it's defined as `{}`? The code in that `if` statement at the end of your constructor should be run when the `document` property is set in your other file below, and should only expect `this.document` to exist.

Comment: If I wanted to run that if statement (end of the constructor) after setting the document but didn't want to have that block of code reside in my other file, what's the best plan of action to get that setup properly?

Comment: Simple way would be to replace ``myLead.document = myDoc`` with ``myLead.setDocument(myDoc)`` as a method of Lead that sets the document internally and executes the helper code. The more complex way would be to use the new [getters and setters in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) to implicitly run a function when accessing a property of the object.

Comment: I was fooling around with prototyping a .setDocument(doc) method on Lead but it didn't seem to take effect, was this because of how crippled the other parts of the code were?

Comment: Probably so. May I suggest that rather than re-invent the wheel (a custom ORM that performs validation on a documents for a MongoDB collection), that you try to use [Mongoose](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose), which handles non-trivial validation entirely for you, and is relatively simple to extend? (It also wraps around the MongoDB library, so you don't need to include that, either.)

Comment: Been there done that. I was using Mongoose for a few days and came to the conclusion that you have to jump through hoops to get the validator's output to be reasonable, also the irc channel and mailing group are like a ghost town.

I don't want to go too crazy and try to re-invent mongoose. I just want access to CRUD actions on a model with validation.

Ideally I want these actions to reside in some generic database module and then I can do stuff like db.findOne('collectionName', function(err) ...) in any of my collection models.

Comment: It just doesn't want to work doing it that way. this.document is always undefined when my validator method tries to access this.document.login.email (or any other property).

Comment: I added a work around solution to my original question, what do you think?

Comment: That change seems reasonable. If you don't need to update the document after instantiating the object, then you're done. You should still be capable of updating the object and having it write the changes out to the database, but that's going into "reinvent Mongoose" territory.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely wrong way even if make this code work as you want. In this example you have  singleton lead. By requesting /register url you want to set 'document' field to this singleton . (IMPORTANT) But requests work asynchronously. Absolutely no guarantee that you save the document, which has just validate. Because new request may overwrite it in lead object. You need to do this logic in request scope. One scope for one request. Not one for all.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't even think about that. Right, the lead is being created/required but is never being set to 'new' for each request -- it's only being set once (singleton I guess?).

Do you think I should just export the connection in the db.js file and then instantiate a new instance of Lead in the route?

Comment: Look at my [form](https://github.com/baryshev/form) module. I think it should help you. I use this flow: 1. pass request data to form (from controller). 2. form validates data and change it if needed. 3. form return 100% trust data or errors. 4. pass data to model (save, update, etc). Model file looks like this:module.exports = function(db) { return { // public methods}; }

Comment: Do you think my edited solution is reasonable or could it be done in a better way? It fixes both problems (I think).

Answer (score 0):

You set `var document = {}` initially, and `{}` is not falsy. Better would be to set as a starting value `document = null` and then after checking for `!document` set `document = {}` before assigning whatever properties you need.

Comment: I originally set it as {} because null was making my script throw errors, it was complaining about trying to set x on 'document.meta.createdAt' but it was undefined. Thanks for the tip.